# Trying to create a new column using paste0 and lapply at the same time but i'm getting an error message

Tags: r

Hey I have a list of dataframes with all the same variables. I want to run a loop or lapply to all the dataframes in the list. Basically a concatenate of col1 and col2 with a space in between, for col1 only the values within the parenthesis and col 2 can be brought as it is.

```
Col1|                                     Col2
It looks like (1) is here                 1234
(2) is here                               5678
Lets do (3)                               9012
Lets preferably work (4) in the equation  3456
```

I would like it for it to look like this for all the values

```
Col1|                                     Col2| Col3
It looks like (1) is here                 1234  1 1234
(2) is here                               5678  2 5678
Lets do (3)                               9012  3 9012
Lets preferably work (4) in the equation  3456  4 3456
```

I tried doing this and it did not work

```
lapply(seq_along(dflist),function(x)
  {
  x$FuzzyMatch<-
    paste0(str_extract(x$col1,  "(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))")," ", x$col2);return(x)
  }
)
```

it's saying `Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :  object 'x' not found`

However when I operate on one data frame I am able to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OP's code, it is looped over the sequence of the list, thus the lambda `x` will be 1, 2, 3, etc... instead of the data.frame/tibble inside the list.  In that case,  we need to extract the list element with `x1 <- dflist[[x]]` and then use `x1` to do the changes.  Instead, we can directly loop over the list and modify/create the column in the `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
map(dflist, ~ .x %>%
          mutate(Col3 = str_c(str_extract(Col1, "\\((\\d+)\\)", 
            group = 1), " ",  Col2)))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
                                      Col1 Col2   Col3
1                It looks like (1) is here 1234 1 1234
2                              (2) is here 5678 2 5678
3                              Lets do (3) 9012 3 9012
4 Lets preferably work (4) in the equation 3456 4 3456

[[2]]
                                      Col1 Col2   Col3
1                It looks like (1) is here 1234 1 1234
2                              (2) is here 5678 2 5678
3                              Lets do (3) 9012 3 9012
4 Lets preferably work (4) in the equation 3456 4 3456
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
lapply(dflist, transform, Col3 = paste(sub(".*\\((\\d+)\\).*", 
       "\\1", Col1), Col2))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
                                      Col1 Col2   Col3
1                It looks like (1) is here 1234 1 1234
2                              (2) is here 5678 2 5678
3                              Lets do (3) 9012 3 9012
4 Lets preferably work (4) in the equation 3456 4 3456

[[2]]
                                      Col1 Col2   Col3
1                It looks like (1) is here 1234 1 1234
2                              (2) is here 5678 2 5678
3                              Lets do (3) 9012 3 9012
4 Lets preferably work (4) in the equation 3456 4 3456
```

#### data

```
dflist <- list(structure(list(Col1 = c("It looks like (1) is here", "(2) is here", 
"Lets do (3)", "Lets preferably work (4) in the equation"), Col2 = c(1234L, 
5678L, 9012L, 3456L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)), structure(list(Col1 = c("It looks like (1) is here", "(2) is here", 
"Lets do (3)", "Lets preferably work (4) in the equation"), Col2 = c(1234L, 
5678L, 9012L, 3456L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)))
```

Comment: Any idea why the previous one didn't work? I will try this.

Comment: @user35131 your previous expected dataset showed brackets as well